# Use diff output to process file in a string / variable

Tags: bash

I am very new to bash scripting and programming of any sort, so this may seem a bit pedestrian... please go easy...

I have two file lists, `$a` and `$b`, containing file basenames. The file extensions have been removed because the files types in `$a` and `$b` are different.

(To view raw image files, previews must be generated in another format - hence different file extensions with the same basenames. The previews are deleted by the user to create list `$a`. The raw files are not touched - list `$b`).

`$b` lists all the basenames of files in folder `b`.

`$a` contains some or all of the basenames in `$b`; that is, some basenames in `$b` may not be in `$a`.

`$a` is the process list... on the files in folder `b`.

To find whether `$a` and `$b` basenames are equivalent or not - this works in practice, but may not be the best way to express it.

```
if [ "$a" == "$b" ]; then 
echo "$a contains all the basenames in $b"; else 
echo "$a does not contain all the basenames in $b" 
fi
```

I think I should be using a loop to look for basenames in `$a` to select files for processing in folder `b` - pseudo code something like this... the detail can come later...

```
for basename in $a; do compare basename in $b
    if [ "basename in $a" == "basename in $b" ]; then
        dcraw [options] rawfile
    else
        ignore rawfile
    fi
done
```

maybe just the conditional statement... I seem hung up on comparing the basenames, whereas looking for one and the other in `$a` and `$b` might be enough?

`$b` is the reference by which to compare basenames in `$a`, ignoring any files in folder `b` whose basenames are not in `$a`.

Is this the logic I should be following - is there a more efficient/better way of looking at this?

---

I'm not sure the rest of this is very helpful based on previous comments...

```
previews=$(ls *.ppm) # not the best way of doing this but it got me started
echo $previews
$a=$(echo "$previews" | sed "s/.*\///" | sed "s/\..*//")
echo $a
raw=$(ls *.raw) # same as above
echo $raw
b=$(echo "$raw" | sed "s/.*\///" | sed "s/\..*//")
echo $b
diff <(echo "$a" ) <(echo "$b")
```

This is the output..

`echo $previews`:

```
IMG_0064.ppm
IMG_0066.ppm
```

`echo $a`:

```
IMG_0064
IMG_0066
```

`echo $raw`:

```
IMG_0064.CR2
IMG_0065.CR2
IMG_0066.CR2
```

`echo $b`:

```
IMG_0064
IMG_0065
IMG_0066

Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 differ # not very helpful
```

That is, `0065` is missing from `$a`, therefore don't process `0065.CR2` (basename `0065` in `$b`) in folder `b`.

The ppm files are small previews of the raw files displayed in an animation, blink script. The previews are deleted to create the process list `$a`.

Comment: Provide the same format for how the files `$a` and `$b` look like?

Comment: It's difficult to guess what output is from what `echo`. Could you please prefix the outputs with something, or insert a delimiter line between them, so that we may tell them apart?

Comment: Without proper quoting, there is no way those `echo` statements could have produced that output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over pairs of values in bash](/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash)

Comment: Also avoid [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: As requested - Inian, do you mean just rename the $a files .CR2?

Comment: So, basically, you do not want a diff of the files, you want a list of those basenames present in both lists?

Comment: Yes... which is the question I needed... that's right. diff is probably not the way to go in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks tripleee - none of that made any sense to begin with, but on second look it is similar to the problem stated. I know that use of ls is not good practice. I will tidy up as I go.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using `cmp` instead of `diff` for binary files:

```
$ dd if=/dev/random of=a bs=1 count=256 # 256 bytes of random data
$ dd if=/dev/random of=b bs=1 count=256 # 256 bytes of random data
$ cmp -s a b # -s stands for silent
$ $?
1
```

so in your code:

```
cmp -s $file1 $file2
res=$?
if [[ $res -eq 1 ]]; then
   # your stuff for diff files
fi
```

Comment: I have changed my question

Answer (score 0):

This works on the last file in $a (the preview base names) - bash is not expanding the variable from what I can tell.

```
    >     # operate on raw files
    >         
    >           for i in $a; do 
    >           dcraw -o 0 -w -h -T $a.$ext
    >           done
```